# Append input field jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, forms, append

Can anybody tell me why if "Append" or "AppendTo" or "After" or "prepend" an input field inside a div which is nested inside the form tag it doesn't work ?
And why if I Append it just after the form tag it works magically fine ?
This is absolutely insane. I need to place the field exactly where it needs to be. An help will be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

```html
 <form id="myform" name="myform" method="post" action="somewhere.php">

    // APPEND <INPUT> IN HERE WORKS !!!!

    <div id="myDiv"> 

        // APPEND <INPUT> IN HERE WONT WORK !!!!

      </div>

    <button type="submit" id="myform"> SAVE THE FORM </button>

 </form>
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. How are you _"appending"_ the new `<input>`? If you're using JavaScript code, please [edit] your question to include it

Comment: FYI `id` attributes **must** be unique in a document. You have two instances of `id="myform"`. If you also have other elements with `id="myDiv"`, that probably explains what's happening

Comment: Thank you. Your reply made me open my eyes widely and I've just find out that my DIVs in Form block where all messed up and I kept appending my code out of the Form..!!! But I still cant understand why the other static fields, out of the Form tag,  were working fine on my submit button !!!! Bootstrap mysteries...  Anyway thanks a lot for your reply...

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know what's wrong, if you don't post your code.
In any case, the problem certainly isn't the div inside the form.

```js
$('#myform').prepend('<input value="1"/>');
$('#myDiv').prepend('<input value="2"/>');
```

```css
form {
  background: #ff9999;
  padding: 1rem;
}
div {
  background: #99ff99;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" name="myform" method="post" action="somewhere.php">

    APPEND INPUT IN HERE WORKS !!!!

    <div id="myDiv"> 

        APPEND INPUT IN HERE WONT WORK !!!!

      </div>

    <button type="submit" id="myform"> SAVE THE FORM </button>

 </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying me. You right but while I was preparing the code for posting in here, I've just realized that my DIVS block were all messed up !! My Append ended up out of the FORMTAG, thats why it didnt work. The silly thing is that while I was debuging the page the others static INPUTS were still working...I dont know how !!!